# I am trying to add flick_video_player package and it gives me version solving failed. error How can i resolve this issue?

Tags: flutter, version, video-player, pubspec.yaml

This is the issue i am facing right now i am using syncfusion_flutter_pdfviewer  package with version 22.2.10 and when i try to add flick_video_player player it gives me this error

```
The current Dart SDK version is 3.2.5.

    Because syncfusion_flutter_pdfviewer >=22.1.34 depends on device_info_plus ^9.0.2 which depends on win32 >=4.0.0 <6.0.0, syncfusion_flutter_pdfviewer   
      >=22.1.34 requires win32 >=4.0.0 <6.0.0.                                                                                                              
    Because wakelock_windows >=0.2.1 depends on win32 ^3.0.0 and wakelock_windows <0.2.1 depends on win32 ^2.0.0, every version of wakelock_windows requires
      win32 ^2.0.0 or ^3.0.0.                                                                                                                               
(1) Thus, syncfusion_flutter_pdfviewer >=22.1.34 is incompatible with wakelock_windows.                                                                     
    And because flick_video_player ^0.4.0 depends on wakelock ^0.5.6 and flick_video_player >=0.3.0 <0.4.0-dev.4 depends on wakelock ^0.5.0+2,
      flick_video_player <0.4.0-dev.4 or >=0.4.0 <0.6.0-∞ requires wakelock >=0.5.0+2 <0.6.0 or ^0.6.0.
    And because flick_video_player >=0.4.0-dev.4 <0.4.0 depends on wakelock ^0.5.0+3 and wakelock >=0.5.0 <0.5.6 depends on wakelock_windows ^0.1.0,
      flick_video_player <0.6.0 requires wakelock_windows ^0.1.0 or wakelock >=0.5.6 <0.6.0 or ^0.6.0.
    And because flick_video_player >=0.6.0 depends on wakelock ^0.6.2 which depends on wakelock_windows ^0.2.0, every version of flick_video_player requires       
      wakelock_windows ^0.1.0 or ^0.2.0.
    And because syncfusion_flutter_pdfviewer >=22.1.34 is incompatible with wakelock_windows (1), syncfusion_flutter_pdfviewer >=22.1.34 is incompatible with      
      flick_video_player.
    So, because innerlight depends on both syncfusion_flutter_pdfviewer ^22.2.10 and flick_video_player any, version solving failed.

The lower bound of "sdk: '>=2.4.0 <3.0.0'" must be 2.12.0 or higher to enable null safety.
```

how can i resolve this issue ?